# Adding a decorator that converts strings to lowercase in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators

So I am new to learning decorators and I have gone through countless tutorials and while I understand and can mostly follow all of the examples, I think the best way to learn, would be to implement a decorator myself.  So I am going to use this example below.  I realize a decorator is not at all necessary to do this, but for the sake of learning, I would like to add a decorator that filters the strings like dog name and breed and turns them into lowercase.  Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
class Dogs:
    totalDogs = 0
    dogList=[]

    def __init__(self, breed, color, age):
        self.breed=breed
        self.color=color
        self.age=age
        Dogs.dogList.append(self.breed)
        Dogs.totalDogs += 1

    def displayDogs(self):
        print "breed: ", self.breed
        print "color: ",self.color
        print "age: ",self.age
        print "list of breeds:", Dogs.dogList
        print "total dogs: ", Dogs.totalDogs

def somedecorator(*args):
    #now what

terrier=Dogs("TeRrIer", "white", 5)
terrier.displayDogs()
retriever=Dogs("goldenRETRIEVER", "brown", 10)
retriever.displayDogs()
```

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for? Is it just lower case like the string.lower() function but you want to implement it using ascii values?

Comment: Um, I'm not really sure what either of those things are that you just asked.  To clarify, none of that matters to me, I'm really just trying to implement a decorator of some sort to learn more about decorators.

Comment: If you want to go to the bit level this post should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569874/how-do-uppercase-and-lowercase-letters-differ-by-only-one-bit/3570520#3570520

Comment: I'm not really asking for help on how to output lowercase strings, I'm asking for help implementing a decorator.  I don't know where to start with the decorator itself, and I'm confused about what to call it on.  For example do I put it above displayDogs() or terrier.displayDogs()

Comment: Decorators are used to modify a function.

For example, if you had "getDogInfo(self)" that returned a string which described all the dogs, you could have a decorator that would modify it's return value and make it lower case or something.

The easiest things to do in a decorator are 1) add code before a the original function, 2) add code that runs after the original function, and 3) Monkey with the arguments of the function. So modifying the print statemetns within the function is a little tougher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A decorator is really just a function that takes a function as an argument and returns another function.

```
def lower_output(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs).lower()
    return wrapper


class Dogs(object):
    totalDogs = 0
    dogList=[]

    def __init__(self, breed, color, age):
        self.breed=breed
        self.color=color
        self.age=age
        Dogs.dogList.append(self.breed)
        Dogs.totalDogs += 1

    @lower_output
    def get_breed(self):
        return self.breed




>>> terrier=Dogs("TeRrIer", "white", 5)
>>> terrier.get_breed()
terrier
```

Comment: thanks for the help, although I'm getting an error that says line 12 lower_output is not defined

Comment: Try defining it further up in the module, I've edited my example for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to simplify it, let's just deal with functions, first. Let's say you have a function that prints something about its arguments:

```
def print_info(breed, name):
    print "The doggie %s's breed is %s." % (name, breed)
```

As such:

```
>>> print_info("Labrador", "Spike")
The doggie Spike's breed is Labrador.
>>> print_info("Pit Bull", "Spot")
The doggie Spot's breed is Pit Bull.
```

Now you want that  function instead to always lowercase the breed. So in a sane way you'd just do this:

```
def manually_lowered_print_info(breed, name):
    print "The doggie %s's breed is %s." % (name, breed.lower())
```

Output is:

```
>>> manually_lowered_print_info("Labrador", "Spike")
The doggie Spike's breed is labrador.
```

But let's say for some reason you very often had to lowercase the first string argument of functions you write so you wanted to abstract this away as a decorator. We want it to look like this and have the same output:

```
@lower_first_arg
def dec_lowered_print_info(breed, name):
    print "The doggie %s's breed is %s." % (name, breed)
```

This is just syntax sugar for this:

```
def tmp_func(breed, name):
    print "The doggie %s's breed is %s." % (name, breed)
dec_lowered_print_info = lower_first_arg(tmp_func)
```

So we want `lower_first_arg` to *return* the transformed `print_info` function. Let's first make a function specifically tailored for the `print_info` function.

```
def lower_first_arg(print_info_func_arg):
    def inner_print_info(breed, name):
        return print_info_func_arg(breed.lower(), name)
    return inner_print_info
```

Does it work? Let's see:

```
>>> transformed_print_info = lower_first_arg(print_info)
>>> print_info("Pit Bull", "Spot")
The doggie Spot's breed is Pit Bull.
>>> transformed_print_info("Pit Bull", "Spot")
The doggie Spot's breed is pit bull.
```

Great! Notice that we are passing `print_info` as an argument to the `lower_first_arg` function, where it gets referred to by the local variable `print_info_func_arg`.

If we use the decorator syntax it works identically:

```
@lower_first_arg
def dec_lowered_print_info(breed, name):
    print "The doggie %s's breed is %s." % (name, breed)
```

Outstanding:

```
>>> dec_lowered_print_info("Pit Bull", "Spot")
The doggie Spot's breed is pit bull.
```

---

Cool, so that's it, really. Now to make the decorator more generic, let's first generalize the names:

```
def generic_lower_first_arg(f):
    def wrapped(arg1, arg2):
        return f(arg1.lower(), arg2)
    return wrapped
```

Now the problem here is this decorator only works on functions of 2 args. Ideally we'd want it to work on any function of 1 arg or more, e.g.:

```
@generic_lower_first_arg
def failed_whatnow(first, last, middle):
    print "%s %s %s" % (first, middle, last)
```

Now, that code will run, but we get an error if we try to call it:

```
>>> failed_whatnow("Bob", "Jones", "The Killer")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    failed_whatnow("Bob", "Jones", "The Killer")
TypeError: wrapped() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What's going on? Well, the decorator took `failed_whatnow` and returned the function it defined, `wrapped`, but that `wrapped` function only takes two arguments! The fix here is to use the varargs syntax. It's also generally a good idea to pass along any keyword args that might be given to the wrapped function.

```
def proper_lower_first_arg(f):
    def wrapped(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
        return f(arg1.lower(), *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

And now it works on all sorts of functions:

```
@proper_lower_first_arg
def proper_whatnow(first, last, middle):
    print "%s %s %s" % (first, middle, last)

@proper_lower_first_arg
def multiplyit(mm, n=3):
    return mm * n
```

Proof:

```
>>> proper_whatnow("Bob", "Jones", "The Killer")
bob The Killer Jones
>>> multiplyit("HaHa.Fool!")
'haha.fool!haha.fool!haha.fool!'
>>> multiplyit("HaHa.Fool!", n=5)
'haha.fool!haha.fool!haha.fool!haha.fool!haha.fool!'
```

Answer (score 0):

A decorator usually is used to modify input arguments or returned values of a function/method.

Method `Dogs.displayDogs` does not return any data (except `None`), so it doesn't make sense saying you want to make strings lowercase. Which strings? You just print the values. So you would do:

```
class Dogs:
    totalDogs = 0
    dogList=[]

    def __init__(self, breed, color, age):
        self.breed=breed
        self.color=color
        self.age=age
        Dogs.dogList.append(self.breed)
        Dogs.totalDogs += 1

    def displayDogs(self):
        print "breed: ", self.breed.lower()
        print "color: ",self.color.lower()
        ...
```

Otherwise you should refactor your code:

```
def make_lower(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        result = [value.lower() for value in result]
        return result
    return wrapper

class Dogs:
    totalDogs = 0
    dogList=[]

    def __init__(self, breed, color, age):
        self.breed=breed
        self.color=color
        self.age=age
        Dogs.dogList.append(self.breed)
        Dogs.totalDogs += 1


    @make_lower
    def getDogs(self):
        return [
            "breed: %s" % self.breed,
            "color: %s" % self.color.lower(),
            ...
        ]
```

The you do

```
terrier = Dogs("TeRrIer", "white", 5)
print terrier.getDogs()
```